# Run protractor in debug mode with @angular/bazel protractor_web_test_suite

Tags: angular, protractor, bazel

I've setup my protractor project like https://github.com/angular/angular-bazel-example using `protractor_web_test_suite`. I can run the tests regularly and everything starts up/passes. I'm now looking to run the tests in debug mode. There isn't too much documentation on what I'm trying to do with Bazel but this is the code that is executing under the hood: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/bazel/src/protractor/protractor_web_test.bzl.

My question is: How do I pass `--inspect-brk` to the node process running protractor? Is this even possible, or am I trying to setup debug incorrectly?